# How do I use the dropbox access token generated to connect my dropbox files to my dropbox console app in android studio

Tags: android

Please I need help in how to connect my personal dropbox files to a dropbox app I created. I want to try it with a trial app I did in android studio for my final year project. All sites I went through shows you should use the generate button but none shows what to do after you have generated the token. Please any help will be very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stackoverflow :) actually there's a full tutorial site on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java#tutorial) where you can find examples to view and upload files and directories. [Here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android/UserActivity.java) is the android example what you need.

The example from Dropbox:

```
public class UserActivity extends DropboxActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(UserActivity.this, getString(R.string.app_key));
        }
    });

    Button filesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.files_button);
    filesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(FilesActivity.getIntent(UserActivity.this, ""));
        }
    });

    Button openWithButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open_with);
    openWithButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openWithIntent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, OpenWithActivity.class);
            startActivity(openWithIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (hasToken()) {
        findViewById(R.id.login_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.email_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.name_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.type_text).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.files_button).setEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.open_with).setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.login_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.email_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.name_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.type_text).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.files_button).setEnabled(false);
        findViewById(R.id.open_with).setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void loadData() {
    new GetCurrentAccountTask(DropboxClientFactory.getClient(), new GetCurrentAccountTask.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FullAccount result) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_text)).setText(result.getEmail());
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_text)).setText(result.getName().getDisplayName());
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_text)).setText(result.getAccountType().name());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Failed to get account details.", e);
        }
    }).execute();
}}
```